# como reducir decimales en textbox c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy mostrando informacion en un textbox de totales, pero al mostrarlos me pone los 4 decimales lo que quiero es que se reduzca a 2, ya lo intente con la propiedad  MaxLength a 2 pero nada.

lo intento con Decimal.ToString() pero nada, e igual con la misma consulta al serividor

```
public void Totales()
        {
            String cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["produccion"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string query = "SELECT ROUND(Subtotal,2,0) As Subtotal,TotalIva,Total FROM CATALOGO_TICKETS WHERE CodigoTicket=@codigoticket";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@codigoticket", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_operacion.Text;
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    txtSubTotal.Text = dr["Subtotal"].ToString();
                    txtIva.Text = dr["TotalIva"].ToString();
                    txtTotal.Text = dr["Total"].ToString();
                }
                conexion.Close();
            }
        }
```

Alguna idea?

por comentario agregue este code

```
string end = txtSubTotal.Text = dr["Subtotal"].ToString("c", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

al correrlo me manda error

> CS1501    No overload for method 'ToString' takes 2 arguments

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer lo siguiente:

```
  var doubl = (double) value;
      doubl = Math.Round(doubl, 2);
      doubl.ToString("0.00",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Esto lo agregaria despues del dr["Subtotal"]? porque ya lo intente pero simplemente me tira error.

Comment: Que error te aparece ???

Comment: CS1501 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 2 arguments

Comment: Lo mas recomendado es que el dr["Subtotal"] lo manejes como decimal o double y luego a ese valor aplicarle el ToString() con la sobre carga

Answer (score 0):

```
                txtSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Subtotal"]).ToString0("N2");
                txtIva.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["TotalIva"]).ToString("N2");
                txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Total"]).ToString("N2");
```

Comment: https://ibb.co/p6TgLb8
Es el error que me marca